# Standard (Linux/GNU) toolset for Mac

Tags: macos, macbook, gnu

I'm quite new to Mac OS but I've already noticed that many tools are not what I used to be. For e.g.,

- sed missed the `-w` option, and
- xargs missed the `-i` option, etc

I'm wondering if it has always been this case, or there are ways to get my familiar Linux/GNU tool set behaviour back in MacOS.

Comment: Pet peeve: macOS command-line utilities *are* standard (they conform to the POSIX specification), they just don't have a lot of GNU extensions that you're used to. You can install GNU versions of utilities [with Homebrew or MacPorts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities), but be aware they may be missing some macOS extensions.

Comment: Despite what Mac enthusiasts will tell you, BSD (which mac is based on) and other *NIXs are not the same creature.  The command line for basic tools (like SED) also differ making scripting for both a PITA.  I addition to this, the Mac tools are  VERY OLD.  You can use [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/) to get some decently modern versions of these tools.  You will then need to figure out how to target the GNU versions.. but that is another question.